# how to flatten multiple structs and get the keys as one of the fields

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, struct

I have this struct schema

```
|-- teams: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- blue: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- has_won: boolean (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- rounds_lost: long (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- rounds_won: long (nullable = true)
|    |-- red: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- has_won: boolean (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- rounds_lost: long (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- rounds_won: long (nullable = true)
```

which I want to turn to this schema

```
+----+-------+-----------+----------+
|team|has_won|rounds_lost|rounds_win|
+----+-------+-----------+----------+
|blue|      1|         13|        10|
| red|      0|         10|        13|
+----+-------+-----------+----------+
```

I already tried `selectExpr(inline(array('teams.*')))`

[inline array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKj1o.png)

but I don't have any idea to get the `team` to one of the fields? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can start by un-nesting the struct using `*` and then use [`stack`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#stack) to "un-pivot" the dataframe. Finally,  un-nest the stats.

```py
from pyspark.sql import Row

rows = [Row(teams=Row(blue=Row(has_won=1, rounds_lost=13, rounds_won=10), 
                      red=Row(has_won=0, rounds_lost=10, rounds_won=13)))]

df = spark.createDataFrame(rows)

(df.select("teams.*")
   .selectExpr("stack(2, 'blue', blue, 'red', red) as (team, stats)")
   .selectExpr("team", "stats.*")
).show()

"""
+----+-------+-----------+----------+
|team|has_won|rounds_lost|rounds_won|
+----+-------+-----------+----------+
|blue|      1|         13|        10|
| red|      0|         10|        13|
+----+-------+-----------+----------+
"""
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been stuck with this for a week!. You're such a great help!